# 18.04 wifi connection lost

Tags: 18.04, wireless

will not stay logged into wifi at home. wifi hot spots it does great. I will have connection then i will lose it and go to a "?" icon on my wifi. anything i can do or check to fix this?

Comment: look at the logs with the terminal command `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be`

`sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2`

And to make these settings permanent do this also

`sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"`